# Why does javac create a ton of .class files?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

so i wrote a java programm which contains some external .jars like SimpleJSON and Selenium. When i compile this programm in intelliJ, it only creates one .class file of my .java file.

But if i compile my .java via command line (javac example.java), it creates like 300+ .class files, including the .class file of my .java

Im just curios why that is? Is this the normal behaviour? Can somebody please explain that to me?

so i expected that compiling with javac creates the same output than compiling within my IDE, but i guess thats just not the right assumption

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;



public class SeleniumWikipedia
{
    public static String searchTerm;
    public static String JSONpath = internal
    public static String JSONoutput =i nternal
    public static String ceo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //readString();
        readJSON();
        ChromeDriver Chrom1 = getDriver();
        Chrom1.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite");
        WebElement searchfield = Chrom1.findElement(By.id("searchInput"));
        Chrom1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        searchfield.sendKeys(searchTerm);
        WebElement searchGo = Chrom1.findElement(By.id("searchButton"));
        searchGo.click();
        checkSuccess(Chrom1);
```

[image: some created class files]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2lq.jpg

File Structure:

```
└───Code
    │   tree.txt
    │
    ├───.vscode
    │       settings.json
    │
    ├───lib
    │       auto-service-1.0-rc6-sources.jar
    │       auto-service-1.0-rc6.jar
    │       auto-service-annotations-1.0-rc6.jar
    │       byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar
    │       client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar
    │       client-combined-3.141.59.jar
    │       commons-exec-1.3.jar
    │       guava-25.0-jre.jar
    │       json-simple-1.1.1.jar
    │       okhttp-3.11.0.jar
    │       okio-1.14.0.jar
    │
    ├───NyxDevKit.PowerShellErrorHandling
    │       Out-Null
    │       PSErrorHandling.Tests.ps1
    │       PSErrorHandlingScript.ps1
    │
    ├───NyxDevKit.Selenium
    │   │   NyxDevKit.Selenium.iml
    │   │   Output.json
    │   │
    │   ├───.idea
    │   │       compiler.xml
    │   │       misc.xml
    │   │       modules.xml
    │   │       vcs.xml
    │   │       workspace.xml
    │   │
    │   ├───Build
    │   ├───ChromeDriver
    │   │       chromedriver.exe
    │   │
    │   ├───out
    │   │   └───production
    │   │       └───NyxDevKit.Selenium
    │   │           │   Output.json
    │   │           │   SeleniumWikipedia.class
    │   │           │
    │   │           └───ChromeDriver
    │   │                   chromedriver.exe
    │   │
    │   └───src
    │           SeleniumWikipedia.java
    │
    └───NyxDevKit.SeleniumSample
            SeleniumParam.json
```

the .class file in the folder out\production is created by intelliJ.

I want to compile the SeleniumWikipedia.java file located in src.

What i do to get the 300+ .class files:

i open a PowerShell, get to the directory where the SeleniumWikipedia.java file is located (src) and then i type in "javac SeleniumWikipedia.java". Then it takes half a minute or so and generates those 300 something .class files  in the src folder (as i not define a other directory) like in shown screenshot

i also get this message shown in PowerShell:

```
warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So it is also a normal behavior that those .class files are not created, when compiling with intelliJ?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz This comment is somewhat confusing - `javac` never extracts `.class` files from external jars!

Comment: This does _not_ seem like normal behavior. Is the command you execute really just `javac  Example.java`? Unless you have 300+ nested/anonymous classes then ending up with 300+ `.class` files is strange indeed. What are some of the names of these excessive `.class` files? What does `Example.java` look like?

Comment: some .class names: AbstractCapabilities.class; BrowserType.class; ChromeDriverCommand.class; FileHandler.class; ... - it seems like those are all .class files from import statements of my .java class (i imported JSONSimple, Selenium and things like filewriter, etc.)

Comment: I honestly cannot think of a reason why executing `javac` would result in the third-party JAR files being extracted and the contents being placed next to your project's `.class` files. If possible, please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: i added some code and an imgur screenshot of some created .class files. I also get this message when using javac, maybe that is a hint or something:     
  warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Dude, the "reproducible" part implies that you don't show *some* code, you show *the* code as well as everything you did on your computer so that you obtained what you observed. Which is fully explained in the link given.

Comment: Please include your project's directory structure, where you place the third-party dependencies, and the _exact_ commands you executed. In other words, describe _exactly_ how you go from your single `.java` file to the 300+ `.class` files.

Comment: okay so if i type "javac -implicit:none SeleniumWikipedia.java - only my main .java is compiled to a .class file. I guess this does the trick..?

Comment: So you do `...\src> javac SeleniumWikipedia.java` and that's it? I'm surprised that even compiles since the dependencies aren't on the classpath/modulepath.

Comment: yes thats correct, the path to the lib folder is stored in my windows 
environment variable CLASSPATH

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Alright, then my guess at the cause of the problem is the presence of the source JARs (e.g. the `*-sources.jar` files). Maybe `javac` sees the source files and that triggers some functionality that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Don’t post a list of file names as a picture.